# cURL Авторизация. Ошибка SSL read: errno -5961

Tags: curl, ssl

Пытаюсь сделать авторизацию на cURL
Прописал заголовки, всю нужную информацию вроде передаю, проверку сертификатов отключил, но в итоге все равно получаю ошибку

```
SSL read: errno -5961
```

вот код который использую

```
$url = 'https://rs24.ru/sl/authorize';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // отправляем на 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0"); 
$header  = array
(
'Connection: keep-alive',
'Content-Language: en',
'Content-Type: text/plain',
'Keep-Alive: timeout=15',
'Location: https://rs24.ru/sl/init',
'Server: QRATOR',
'Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains',
'Transfer-Encoding: chunked',
'X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // возвратить то что вернул сервер
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // следовать за редиректами
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);// таймаут4
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/my_cookies.txt'); // сохранять куки в файл
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/my_cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // использовать данные в post
$login = array(
'event' => '',
'isFirstEntry' => 'true',
'targetUrlParameter' => 'home.htm',
  'username' => 'тут логин',
  'password' => 'тут пароль'
);
curl_setopt(($ch), CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $login);
$result1 = curl_exec($ch);
//echo $result1;

$url2 ='https://rs24.ru/product/638200';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/my_cookies.txt');
$result2 = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) 
{
   print curl_error($ch);
   exit;
}
else
{
  echo $result2;
}
curl_close($ch);
```

подскажите в чем может быть проблема. Заранее спасибо!